# How to force Maven in IntelliJ to pull specific dependency from local .m2 repository

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, lib

### Introduction

In a specific project I inherited we have a dependency as a `jar` file that is a custom wrapper/servlet for `simple-capcha`.
They told me to make specific changes to the small wrapper capcha project, and produce the `JAR` - then test it in the main project.

Then I had to get the second main project to use the new `JAR` as the dependency (instead of the file located on the company artifactory).

### Current Process

Below I describe the process I am using that I feel is very inefficient.
I produce using maven the `jar` file from the small project.
I then go to the local .m2 repository and replace the JAR that exists there (downloaded from artifactory) with the new one.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>test.company.something.captcha</groupId>
            <artifactId>captcha-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.90</version>
        <!--    <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:/Users/mbakopoulos/Dropbox/_captcha/target/captcha-common-0.90.jar</systemPath>-->
        </dependency>
```

Finally, I uncomment, and comment the `<scope>` and `<systemPath>` tags (with auto-import enabled) so that intellij detects the 2 changes, and forces maven to pulls from the local `.m2` repository replacing the `maven:library` in the project.

Finally, the specific JAR contains a `HTTPServlet` that is actually being used in the `web.xml` of the main project. At some point when I changed the dependency version I was getting a `classNotFoundException` after `JBOSS` deployed the `war`:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>TheCaptcha</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class><servlet>
    <servlet-name>StickyCaptcha</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.company.something.CaptchaServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>width</param-name>
        <param-value>250</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>height</param-name>
        <param-value>60</param-value>
    </init-param>       
</servlet>
```

### Question

What is the best way to develop and test a dependency that was/is included usually as a dependency? Could I get rid of the pom.xml entry, and include the other project as a module?

I am using intelliJ IDEA 2016.

Finally, **Is there anyway to connect to two modules/projects together?**
I suspect there should be.

Comment: Any reason you didn't just make a new version `0.90-A` or similar ?

Comment: @vikingsteve I initially tried it like that, and included the dependency using `scope` and `systemPath` but I was getting a `classNotFoundException` when I debugged the main project. So I gave up and used the same version/file-name.

Comment: Can you drop `scope` and `systemPath` completely and put the artifact with a new version (`0.90-A` or whatever) in `C:/Users/mbakopoulos/.m2/repository/test/company/something/captcha/captcha-common`. As long as thats the default local repository your build should find it ok. Remove any `lastUpdated` references there also.

Comment: @vikingsteve I can see how that would avoid over-riding the previous JAR version - more cleaner/organized. Wouldn't I still need to edit the `pom.xml` dependency every time I put an updated `.jar` file in the `m2` repository? Is there anyway to connect to two modules/projects together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving my comments to an extended answer here.

Firstly, having multiple different versions of *any* released maven artifact with the *same* version number is asking for a lot of problems!! If at all possible, avoid doing this. The numbering system can always be extended (e.g. `0.90.1` or `0.90-CUSTOM-1` or `0.09-A`).

Secondly, using `systemPath` for a dependency is non-standard. Try to work with versions "normally", so that they live in your `M2_HOME\.m2\repository` when working locally (and can be uploaded to your artifactory or nexus to be shared with colleagues).

Now, as far as automating the build / test process, you have a few options. You can either build `0.90.1` and `0.90.2` and update the version for the `<dependency>` section every time the dependency is rebuilt.

Or you can use snapshot versioning. `0.90.1-SNAPSHOT` indicates to maven that it's a snapshot build. Whenever you rebuild a project with a snapshot dependency, it will look to see if that dependency has been changed.

Lastly you could move the dependency into the same project as your main project as a submodule. Then you avoid having to define an explicit dependency between projects.

Hope this helps...